# how to code click event for an image inside html text box

Tags: javascript, image, textbox, click

i have a html text box with an background image as below in asp.net mvc page. an now i want to write click event for that back ground image alone.

```
      <input type="text" id="txtProjectCode"  readonly="readonly" style="background-image:url('/Content/Images/remove.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:right;
" />
```

how can i write click event handler for the background image of the html text box  in javascript?
if not in javascript any work around to do it?

Comment: I don't think it is possible

Comment: it is possible, use mapping for that with an overlay. I'll try to code it and explain it if it worked out.

Comment: You want to track the click on the input, but not _inside_ the text block?

Comment: but I would like to know what the purpose is for that ?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you want exactly. But as far I understood I think you can set a class for you input and then get the element with the class and set the click event.

Comment: @CME64 if he useses an overlay, he wouldn't be able to select the text in the area in particular place, would he?

Comment: @david yes he can, by controling the area he wants to use for focus and force trigger the focus, or just trigger the focus from the overlay's click event, and for selecting text, that could be done manually from the overlay

Comment: @subash I'm still curious, what are you trying to achieve using that ?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the input element within a div, and create an image element, set CSS `position: relative;` on the parent div, and set `position: absolute;` on the image, and by specifying the `top/left` properties of the image, you can position the image to overlay the input. If you want to overlay the input background, you can make the overlay image transparent and assign click event on the transparent image and it should work. Something like:

```
<div style="position: relative;">

<input type="text" id="txtProjectCode" readonly="readonly" style="background-image:url('/Content/Images/remove.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:right; " />
<img src="img.png" style="position: absolute; right: 0;" />

</div>
```

Comment: that's exactly what I meant :) +1

Answer (score 0):

here is how to implement the overlay with js: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NFvWa/)**

css:

```
#overlay{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
    opacity:0.2;
    z-index:5;
}
#field{
    /*background-image:url('');*/
}
```

html:

```
<input id="field" type="text" /> 
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

js:

```
console.log(parseInt($('#field').css('border-width')));
var border = parseInt($('#field').css('border'));
$('#overlay').css({'width':($('#field').width()+2*border)+'px','height':($('#field').height()+3*border)+'px','left':($('#field').offset().left)+'px','top':($('#field').offset().top)+'px'});

$('#overlay').click(function(){
    console.log('clicked');
    $('#field').focus();
}).mousedown(function(){
    $('#field').mousedown();
}).mouseup(function(){
    $('#field').mouseup();
});
```

if you want to add text selection => add this `$('#field').select();` inside mousedown trigger or mouseup

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/que42/css-background-image-onclickstions/96682

It'st not possible this way, because background isn't part of the DOM. You can only acheve this by catching `click event` of the textarea and then examinating the coordinates of click.